# Hibernate transformer null pointer exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm trying to get `hibernate`'s `ResultTransformer` to work for fetching an entire table but keep getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
List result = session.createQuery(
          "FROM com.maps.model.Book")
          .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(Book.class))
          .list();
```

Is there a way to get this to work for an entire table using `HQL`?

(The reason I'm doing this is that I have a project with 50 plus tables which I need to cache and I don't want to write 50 different methods.)

EDIT: the exception stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.initialize(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:116)
at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanResultTransformer.java:85)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:95)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultList(QueryLoader.java:438)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2263)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2258)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1161)
at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
at com.maps.manager.DatabaseManager.findAll(DatabaseManager.java:65)
at com.maps.manager.DatabaseManager.main(DatabaseManager.java:40)
```

Comment: Could you add the first few lines of the NPE stacktrace?

Comment: So if you go to the source of AliasToBeanResultTransformer on line 116 what is the object that's null there.

Comment: I wish I had the time to dive into Hibernate's internals. Unfortunately I don't. I have an app to develop and a deadline to meet.

Comment: This is the fastest way to find out what you're missing. In most IDE's you should be able to just ctrl+click into 'the internals'. And no one on here should dive into the hibernate code just because you don't have the time. Should take like 15 seconds max.